# merging or mapping multiple categories

Tags: menu, category-products

I'm using 1.9 . I have separate root categories for men and women. Each have subcategories of hats and shirts. I also have root categories of hats and shirts that were recently added. They were input after all the products were already associated with the correct sub category under men and women. Is there any easy way to map the already setup categories to the new ones in magento or run a sql statement to accomplish this ? Ideally I would like to the hats and shirts root categories to contain all products with that category without gender classification.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do sql inserts directly.
The product-category association is kept in the table `catalog_category_product`.
So you just have to look for the entries with `category_id` the id of your hats subcategory and duplicate it changing the `category_id` to the hats root category id.